# How to fill more than one input form using onlick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a live search with AJAX.

Then when I click the result I want the result to fill 5 input fields.

Here is what I have tried:

Here is my `cari.php` file:

```
while ($cari_karyawans = $cari_karyawan->fetch()) { ?>
   <div class="result" onclick="fill('nik','<?php echo $cari_karyawans['nik_k_ptayp']; ?>')">
   <div class="result" onclick="fill('nama','<?php echo $cari_karyawans['nama_k_ptayp']; ?>')">
   <div class="result" onclick="fill('lokasi','<?php echo $cari_karyawans['jabatan_k_ptayp']; ?>')">
   <div class="result" onclick="fill('divisi','<?php echo $cari_karyawans['divisi_k_ptayp']; ?>')">
   <div class="result" onclick="fill('jabatan','<?php echo $cari_karyawans['lokasi_k_ptayp']; ?>')">
   <a><small class="text-muted"><i><?php echo $cari_karyawans['nik_k_ptayp']; ?></i></small> / <small class="text-muted"><i><?php echo $cari_karyawans['nama_k_ptayp']; ?></i></small></a>
 </div></div></div></div></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is how I try to fill the result:

```
function fill(nik, nama, lokasi, divisi, jabatan) {
   $('#nik').val(nik);
   $('#nama').val(nama);
   $('#lokasi').val(lokasi);
   $('#divisi').val(divisi);
   $('#jabatan').val(jabatan);
   $('#display').hide();
}
```

Here is my input file:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nik">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lokasi">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="divisi">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="jabatan">
```

Comment: You have a loop? Since this question is not really PHP related, can you please post a `<>` snippet with RENDERED HTML and relevant script? If you want to fill more than one field then you need to parse the result. They you are better off returning JSON than HTML

Comment: @mplungjan maybe u right, but im not understand JSON, i try what i can...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JS function `fill` should be :

```
function fill(id, value) {
   $('#'+id).val(value);
}
```

Because you already sending the `id` as the first argument and the `value` as the second.

Comment: ah i see, so the first is id, the second is value. thanks. its work